# Creating a panel on different web-sites

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm developing a chrome extension with panel (just a div element) injecting to page within contentscript. The problem is that some elements with CSS-property "position: fixed" from loaded page (e.g. youtube.com) are appering above the panel. So, how to get rid of this (without iframing page)?

Comment: Usually the most reliable option is create an iframe in the web page with `src` pointing to a page in your extension which is exposed via `web_accessible_resources` in manifest.json. It's automatically excluded from page CSP so that's not a problem. See also [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12783217)

Comment: @wOxxOm this won't work cause some of website elements are fixed and appears above my panel

Comment: You can set iframe's `style` attribute accordingly e.g. "display:fixed; z-index:2147483647 !important"

Comment: @wOxxOw thanks, I will keep it on mind if there won't be better ideas... I need to make them positioning relatively to their parent as the best variant.